# Rails Link_to with Loop - RESTful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

A question that I hope you can answer for a Q&A app. Still very new with Rails. It should be fairly simple but there is a small issue that I run into whenever I am trying to create a list of links to show up that point to a RESTful route from a loop.

Here's the code for the controller:

users_controller.rb

```
def list
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = User.find(:all, :select => :name)
end

def quiz
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = User.find(:all, :select => :name)
end
```

Here's the code for the view:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <ul>
    <%- @users.each do |link| %>
      <li><%= link_to link.name, quiz_user_path(@user, @quiz) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Here's the code for the route:

```
resources :users do 
  get 'quiz', :on => :member
end
```

What I want to do is generate individual links based on the name of the users and then link to the quiz page for that specific user. I'm pretty sure that something needs to be changed for the code in my view. Right now, all I'm getting is a link that all points to the current user which in this case is user 4. (`http://localhost:3000/users/4/quiz`)

Thanks for any quick tips to solve this.

Comment: Figured it out following the advice below and also one little change in the controller.  Changed "@users = User.find(:all, :select => :name)" to  "@users = User.find(:all)". Took out the :select => :name. Voila! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are using the same @user instance variable for each link. Instead you need to use the variable set in your loop. The code below should work as expected:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <ul>
    <%- @users.each do |user| %>
      <li><%= link_to user.name, quiz_user_path(user) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I also renamed the variable from `link` to `user`, for clarity, since your iterating through users not links.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this shows up with an error: "undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass". If I use @user instead, then I get what I had before which is a list of links that all points to the current user which in this case is user 4. (http://localhost:3000/users/4/quiz). Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Figured it out.  Changed "@users = User.find(:all, :select => :name)" to  "@users = User.find(:all)". Took out the :select => :name. Voila! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your current route map `quiz_user_path` needs only one variable. Try to remove `@quiz`.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I use @user instead, then I get what I had before which is a list of links that all points to the current user which in this case is user 4 who is an admin. (http://localhost:3000/users/4/quiz) Any more ideas?

Comment: Figured it out.  Changed "@users = User.find(:all, :select => :name)" to  "@users = User.find(:all)." Took out the :select => :name. Voila! Thanks again.