# Easy Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, link-to

I'm iterating through a collection of results, and I have this `link_to` in my code:

```
<%= link_to "", "#{expo.id}/edit" %>
```

I expected it go to `<domain>/exhibitions/3/edit`.
I'm already in the `/exhibitions` page so that's where I got that from. The  problem is, is that it goes to `<domain>/exhibitions/3` and ends there. For some reason it doesn't tag on the `edit` portion of the URL. Can anyone help? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The code is wrapped in this:

```
<% @exhibition.each do |expo| %>
    <%= link_to "", expo_edit_path(:id) %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've run `rake routes` and I did have the incorrect edit path. Now the problem is the URL. The URL literally becomes: `http://localhost:3000/exhibitions/id/edit` It literally writes out the word `id`.

This is my new `link_to` statement: `<%= link_to "", edit_exhibition_path(:id) %>`

The error is as follows:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ExhibitionsController#edit
>       Couldn't find Exhibition with 'id'=id

Comment: hmm, i think your two sections are now out of sync after edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like

```
link_to "text", edit_expo_path(expo)
```

You should be use a route as defined in config/routes.rb - read up on rails routing to see the format.

You may find https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141379/631619 helpful.
Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419670/631619

Comment: I'm still getting this error: `undefined method "expo_edit_path" for #<#<Class:0x007ff753602be0>:0x007ff74d83c5b0>`

Comment: Corrected.  Also please do `rake routes` and see what paths exist.  It's possible you will need to add it.  Post the results of that in your question.

Comment: You need to put the expo object or the expo.id there.

Comment: I am looking for a part time RoR job. do you have any to offer ? I'll delete my comment once you see it..